# Kaniko failing to build docker image extracting tar from stdin

Tags: kaniko

I am attempting to build a docker image through kaniko in our jenkins pipeline using the following command:

```sh
/kaniko/executor -f `pwd`/Dockerfile \
                        -c `pwd` \
                        --insecure=true \
                        --insecure-registry=docker-registry.default:5000 \
                        --cache=true \
                        --cache-repo=docker-registry.default:5000/${REPOSITORY} \
                        --destination ${REPOSITORY}:${VERSION}
```

when running the following step

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache ca-certificates tar openssh && \
    curl -L --output - https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/helm-v2.13.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz | tar xvz && \
    mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/bin/helm && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/helm && \
    rm -rf linux-amd64 && \
    rm -f /var/cache/apk/*
```

I get the following error

```
gzip: invalid magic
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 2
```

This used to work a while ago, but it no longer works now.